# How to use Firebird to show all data excluding the present month?

Tags: sql, firebird

What command should I use to show all data, excluding the present month? e.g. present month is `3.2015`

My DB Structure

```
Doc_Code     Doc_Date
BM123431     3.4.2013  or older
BM123423     12.6.2013
BM123456     13.6.2013
BM331234     10.8.2013
BM123423     9.9.2014
BM544223     12.10.2014
BM123454     6.3.2015
```

Comment: What data do you want to show? Or you mean date instead of data? Could you provide a example what do you have now and what do you expect?

Comment: i mean from the first record to present record.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have records with a date in the future and it is actually a date, and not a `TIMESTAMP`, you can determine the date limit by extracting the day of the month using [`EXTRACT`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-extract.html) and subtracting it from the current date using [`DATEADD`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-dateadd.html). The result is the last day of the previous month:

```sql
SELECT doc_code, doc_date
FROM mytable
WHERE doc_date <= DATEADD(-1 * EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) DAY TO CURRENT_DATE)
```

If you also have dates in the future and you only want to exclude the current month, you could also do something like

```sql
SELECT doc_code, doc_date
FROM mytable
WHERE NOT (
   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM doc_date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM doc_date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)
)
```

This will also work if all your dates are in the past, and it will also work with timestamps instead of dates, but it might be less performant for large numbers of records.